# How should I reference services in my controller functions without using scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

After reading several [articles](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html) on avoiding scope soup and referencing the [Google Guidelines](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html#controllers) for building controllers I have been left with one burning question. How should I reference my injected 
dependencies within my controller?

My approach thus far is to put the services on my object but I'm not exactly happy with that as now my services are exposed to the outside world (the template markup).
What is the correct approach to build a controller without directly referencing $scope, and have my injected dependencies available to the controller but not exposed publicly.

As you can see below my work around is to put $http on 'this' and then reference it in my prototyped 
functions. Not my ideal choice for the aforementioned reasons.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Tn6Jkk06Zdu92uTM0UdU?p=preview

```
DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-rc2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body ng-controller="textController as txtCtrl">

<h1>{{txtCtrl.greeting}}</h1>
<button ng-click="txtCtrl.getData()">Get Names</button>
<hr>
{{txtCtrl.names | json}}
<script>

  var textController = function($http){
    this.greeting="Hello World";
    this.$http = $http;
  }

  textController.prototype.alert = function(){
    alert(this.greeting);
  }

  /*retrieve test data from //filltext.com*/
  textController.prototype.getData = function(){
    var that = this;

    this.$http({
      method: 'GET', 
      url: 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}'

    })
    .success(function(data){
      that.names=data;
    })
    .error();
  }

  angular.module("app",[])
  .controller("textController",textController);

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do is to create a closure variable using IIFE and keep reference of `http service` outside the controller, and use it in the controller.

```
  (function(){
      var _$http; //<-- Here a private  variable

     ......

      /*retrieve test data from //filltext.com*/
      textController.prototype.getData = function(){
        var that = this;

       _$http({ //<-- Use it
          method: 'GET', 
          url: 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}' })...
         //...
      }

      angular.module("app").controller("textController",textController);

 })();
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C0cV0z?p=preview)**

Or add a property to the constructor instead of its instance.

```
(function(){

    var textController = function($http){
        this.greeting="Hello World";
        textController._$http = $http; //<-- Here set it
      }

      //....

      /*retrieve test data from //filltext.com*/
      textController.prototype.getData = function(){
        var that = this;

        textController._$http({ //<-- Use it
          method: 'GET', 
          url: 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10&fname={firstName}&lname={lastName}'})...
         //...
      }
     //...
     angular.module("app").controller("textController",textController);
})();
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYGo33?p=preview)**

Here is how you can explicitly annotate your dependencies (unless you use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which will take of it while minification)

```
 angular.module("app").controller("textController",['$http', 'blah', textController]);
```

Or

```
 textController.$inject = ['$http', 'blah'];
```

However i would just leave the responsibility of making ajax calls and any data mapping to a service:-

Example:-

```
  angular.module("app").service('UserService', ['$http', function($http){
       this.getUsers = function(searchObj){ //Get the input and set your url
        return $http({
          method: 'GET', 
          url: 'http://www.filltext.com/?rows=10',
          params: searchObj  //<-- Pass params
        });

       }
   }]);
```

And just inject userService in the controller.

```
 var textController = function(userSvc){
    this.greeting="Hello World";
    this.userSvc = userSvc;
  }

....

  /*retrieve test data from //filltext.com*/
  textController.prototype.getData = function(){
    var that = this;
     //Call service with argument
    this.userSvc.getUsers({firstName:$scope.fn, lastName:$scope.ln}).success(function(data){
      that.names=data;
    })...;
  }

 ....
  angular.module("app").controller("textController",['UserService', textController]);
```

**[Plnk3](http://plnkr.co/edit/qAEh47?p=preview)**

Comment: This is definitely cleaner. Much preferred over my current solution. I will wait for other users (if) to chime in but this looks like a winner.

Comment: @mccainz Added one more way. However anybody can get hold of an `http` reference using angular.injector.

Comment: Looking at them both, I think  I prefer the constructor method but I am curious as to which you would leverage for yourself?

Comment: @mccainz I use typescript so it gets little uglier while going with first approach, so i always use it attached to the controller instance, but i dont use controller As syntax, instead i had written a syntactic sugar for copying function and property reference from controller instance to scope. But i wouldn't worry too much i guess. Because if you really want to you can always get hold of http reference using angular.injector.

Comment: @mccainz Updated answer on details on how you want to take care of your dependencies while minification using explicit annotation

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking too hard about this. If getData() needs to be accessible from our ( view ) html then it should be attached to the scope.

Comment: Nopes Op is talking about the `$http` attached to the controller instance which in turn is attached to the scope via property with the name of controller alias.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case I would use the injector manual to keep a reference to $http in a closure.

```
 var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');
```

[Here is an updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VJsMoef1HhLfjYWzOezE?p=preview).
This way you can keep the private things inside your controller.

EDIT: just noticed that is way similar to @PSL solution. Sorry, I didn't notice his first solution.
However, I'm bringing the manual injector, so I'm keeping this answer if that's ok by you!
EDITEDIT: Updated the plunker to be a bit more testable.

Comment: No, I'm just using it manual. I don't inject in a controller that doesn't need it, this way I'm injecting it in a closure where I need it.

Comment: Thats what, you are missing the point of dependency injection.. :) One of the Solid principles.

Comment: I'm not a fan of bypassing the dependency subsytem when it is avaialble, but one point comes to mind when looking at your code. Your approach would work with minification. Would not my current approach break in that regards?

Comment: I'll update the example so it will use the default injector system.
@PSL, I do test my controllers. It becomes indeed somewhat harder to inject a mock. I'll update my answer ;)

Comment: @mccainz Your approach would not break if you use proper dependency injection pattern. i.e `angular.module("app").controller("textController",['$http',textController]);` Also with controller aproact you can inject dependencies like `textController.$inject=['$http', 'blah']` that is the documented and advised way, using injector to inject dependencies is a hack (or in some cases due to design issues you may be foreces to hack it to avoid circular reference ).

Comment: @mccainz, yes, your approach would break. I'll updated my plunk to reflect the question a bit better, and to be a bit more testable then using the injector manual.

Comment: @mccainz Your dependency would be `$injector` instead of `$http`. What would you do if you have other services injected as well? It the same case not just for http right.. And of course you can mock http.. :D You dont inject a mock for http generraly you mock the service or use httpbackend wherever necessary. But this call is right from the controller, which well can be avoided anyways if it is abstracted out the ajax calls in a service rather than doing it in a controller.

Comment: @PSL, you are correct, no issues with dependency injection. My brain tripped. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @mccainz I am going to update answer with much better approach. Abstracting your http calls to a service.

Comment: Oh I understand that those calls should be in a service I simply put together a barebones solution for plnkr. But by all means for posterity continue on :)

Comment: @mccainz Yup... Check out my answer.