# Is there a pattern for consistent declaration of $scope variables in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS just looks messy and is hard to read. There is a model that exists in some very abstract netherworld accessed by $scope in controllers. Once I have a controller 100 lines long, a partial template 50 lines long with 15 directives and messy CSS class behaviors, it gets real difficult to keep tract of the variables, what they do, and where they are located in the code.

I'm looking at a Todo app example:

```
angular.module('todomvcApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, Todo, filterFilter, $location) {
    $scope.todos = [];
    $scope.newTodo = '';
    $scope.editedTodo = null;
    $scope.status = $location.search().q || '';

//.............

    $scope.$watch('todos', function () {
      $scope.remainingCount = filterFilter($scope.todos, { completed: false }).length;
      $scope.completedCount = $scope.todos.length - $scope.remainingCount;
      $scope.allChecked = !$scope.remainingCount;
    }, true);

//............

    $scope.editTodo = function (id) {
      $scope.editedTodo = $scope.todos[id];
      $scope.originalTodo = angular.extend({}, $scope.editedTodo);
    };

//............

    $scope.revertEditing = function (id) {
      $scope.todos[id] = $scope.originalTodo;
      $scope.doneEditing(id);
    };


  });
```

Here are the some of the $scope variables that require initialization:

```
$scope.todos
$scope.newTodo
$scope.editedTodo
$scope.status
```

However, why are other $scope variables that don't require initialization also not defined early by the author? For example

```
$scope.orginialTodo
```

It makes the code very difficult to read both in the partial template and in the controller. Is there a structure or pattern that helps cleaning variable organization up in Angular?

Comment: Actually, it sounds like a almighty controller. Divide it up in additional directives!

Answer (score 1):

I personally find that using _.extend ( or angular.extend ) to initialize / define scope properties looks cleaners than the $scope.XX = X once per line approach, and helps the readability of the files.

I also personaly always initialize variables in the beginning of the controller / link fn, even if the variable will be set asynchronously. This allow to see all thevariables very fast when you work with one file, without missing the one that are initialized later.

and the more variables you have, the more true it is.

```
_.extend($scope, {
    todos       : [],
    newTodo     : '',
    editedTodo  : null // even if if will be initialized later
});
```

You example would be more or less the following :

```
angular.module('todomvcApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, Todo, filterFilter, $location) {

        _.extends($scope, {
            todos : [],
            newTodo : '',
            editedTodo : null,
            status : $location.search().q || ''
        });

        // .............

        $scope.$watch('todos', function (todos) {
            _.extend($scope, {
                remainingCount : filterFilter(todos, { completed: false }).length,
                completedCount : todos.length - $scope.remainingCount,
                allChecked     : $scope.remainingCount 
            });
        }, true);

        // ............

        $scope.editTodo = function (id) {
            $scope.editedTodo = $scope.todos[id];
            $scope.originalTodo = angular.extend({}, $scope.editedTodo);
        };

        // ............

        $scope.revertEditing = function (id) {
            $scope.todos[id] = $scope.originalTodo;
            $scope.doneEditing(id);
        };


    });
```

Comment: I just don't understand why the Todo tutorial example uses $scope.originalTodo in the controller. The originalTodo variable isn't used in the HTML template. It wasn't initialized early so other developers can easily find it. I just declared var originalTodo and replaced all the instances of $scope.originalTodo with it without any problems. I thought the TodoMVC apps were supposed to be solid examples of the code (http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/). It's just messy.

Comment: Looks like Scope Soup with secret sauce. You are still hanging everything on scope which is not a recommended pattern.

Comment: @mccainz please give me one of the scope property in his example which would not be necessary to expose in the scope. global exposing is not recommended ( but naming it a pattern is just wrong too ), but that's not the question here.

Comment: None of his properties have to be hung directly on scope. THe examples I gave below are directly from Google's Angular style guide and demonstrate how to build your controller avoiding scope. If you have any desire to follow Google's best practices and migrate your code to Angular 2.0 then it's worth following the recommended design from the team.

Comment: that's not the question, period. And speaking about migration to a major version not even in EA phase is even more out of the subjet. imho. If you wanna use getters everywhere and stop using $scope in angular 1.2 / 1.3 that's your choice, but that's not imho a smart move. Migrating will be a pain in the ass anyway, man.

Comment: The approach you suggest is a continuation of the Scope Soup 'pattern'. You are just front loading the properties with extend which at least localizes the properties to one place but is absolutely not required when you follow the simple guidelines put forward by Google. Build your controller as a function and put your properties on this. It is easy and recommended.

Comment: scope soup is just going to be replaced with controller soup when you really are working with data and not functions, man. $scope.posts = [] or ctrl.posts = [] have the same lisibility issue. No clean way until ATscript / ECMA6. you aware of that ? if you are so sure of your answer, please refactor his code with this approach instead of pasting another example from the ng-2.0-wanabe hello word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64497/discussion-between-mccainz-and-pierre-gayvallet).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Basically, avoid scope soup.
Declare your properties in your constructor and access them using 'this'.
You should avoid building up your scope object...

> Why? Putting methods and properties directly onto the controller, instead of building up a scope object, fits better with the Google Closure class style. Additionally, using 'controller as' makes it obvious which controller you are accessing when multiple controllers apply to an element. Since there is always a '.' in the bindings, you don't have to worry about prototypal inheritance masking primitives.

After Version 1.2 the controller 'as' syntax makes this even more streamlined.

As a question which may naturally arise from this method may be, "How do I access my injected services outside the constructor"?...

[How should I reference services in my controller functions without using scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260444/how-should-i-reference-services-in-my-controller-functions-without-using-scope)

[Angular Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html#controllers)

**Syle Guide Examples**

Without using Controller alias

```
<div ng-controller="hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl"/>
  <span ng-class="homeCtrl.myColor">I'm in a color!</span>
  <span>{{homeCtrl.add(5, 6)}}</span>
</div>


 /**
 * Home controller.
 */
hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.homeCtrl = this; // This is a bridge until Angular 1.2 controller-as
  this.myColor = 'blue';
};


hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl.prototype.add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};
```

**After Version 1.2, using Controller-as Syntax**

```
<div ng-controller="hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl as homeCtrl"/>
  <span ng-class="homeCtrl.myColor">I'm in a color!</span>
  <span>{{homeCtrl.add(5, 6)}}</span>
</div>

/**
 * Home controller.
 */
hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl = function() {
  this.myColor = 'blue';
};

hello.mainpage.HomeCtrl.prototype.add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};
```

**And finally, an attempt at refactoring the original Todo using these guidelines (After 1.2 guide)**

```
var MainCtrl = function($timeout, Todo, filterFilter, $location){

  var that =this;

  this.todos = [];
  this.newTodo = '';
  this.editedTodo = null;
  this.originalTodo = null;
  this.status = $location.search().q || '';


  this.$watch('todos',function(){
    that.remainingCount = filterFilter(that.todos, { completed: false }).length;
    that.completedCount = that.todos.length - that.remainingCount;
    that.allChecked = !that.remainingCount;
  });
};

MainCtrl.prototype.editTodo = function (id) {
  this.editedTodo = this.todos[id];
  this.originalTodo = angular.extend({}, this.editedTodo);
};

MainCtrl.prototype.revertEditing = function(){
  this.todos[id] = this.originalTodo;
  this.doneEditing(id);
};

MainCtrl.$inject=['$timeout', 'Todo', 'filterFilter', '$location'];
```